# Load template from another theme in local.xml magento

Tags: magento, themes

Is it possible to load a template file from another theme from a layout file? So instead of something like

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="page/template_links" name="customvars" as="customVars" template="page/html/customvars.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

One might have either:

```
 <reference name="head">
    <block type="page/template_links" name="customvars" as="customVars" template="page/html/customvars.phtml" template="otherTheme" />
</reference>
```

or:

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="page/template_links" name="customvars" as="customVars" template="/app/design/frontend/default/otherTheme/page/html/customvars.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: Why would this be necessary? There are *four* possible locations for a template file within a single configuration scope...

Comment: I'm wanting to load different templates for a block based on, for example, different `get` variable values. I have the functionality built to process blocks or not based on these values, but it would be nicer to have the option to specify a different theme rather than just a different template file.

Comment: Or were you suggesting that it was already possible to specify a different theme for the template?

Comment: Because the request is involved, I'd be inclined to let the controller layer inform the view of the change. This could be done directly in the controller action or more broadly using an event observer. I'd be happy to offer a solution for either.

Comment: Thanks @benmarks that's very kind. What I'm currently doing for the other layout switches is extending the `Mage_Core_Model_Layout`, not sure if `controller action` or `event observer` fits better with this (if either), but my instinct says `controller`?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at `Mage_Core_Block_Template::getTemplateFile()` this is not possible in standard Magento.

```
public function getTemplateFile()
{
    $params = array('_relative'=>true);
    $area = $this->getArea();
    if ($area) {
        $params['_area'] = $area;
    }
    $templateName = Mage::getDesign()->getTemplateFilename($this->getTemplate(), $params);
    return $templateName;
}
```

What you would need is to set `$params['_package']` and `$params['_theme']` in the code. As a starting point you could store this information in block parameters and then copy it to the `$params` array.

But you can specify custom themes for product and category packages - maybe this is already helpful?

Comment: Thanks again Alex. Are you suggesting recreating the above function, or is there a way to `Get`/`Set` the `$params` array from another module?

Comment: You could make an own module that rewrites the `Mage_Core_Block_Template` and adds this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Using an event observer it is possible to inject custom rendering configuration prior to rendering instruction compilation. As it happens, this occurs tangential to controller action execution, which seems appropriate given the involvement of the request object. The event to observe is `controller_action_layout_load_before`, and this is the observer logic:

```
class Some_Observer
{
    /**
     * Observer to inject update handles via query string.
     *
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $o
     * @return void
     */
    public function addQueryStringHandle(Varien_Event_Observer $o)
    {
        $update  = $o->getLayout()->getUpdate();
        /* @var $update Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update */

        $query = $o->getAction()->getRequest()->getQuery();

        if (is_array($query) && count($query)) {
            foreach ($query as $name => $param) {
                if($this->_isValidXmlName($name)) {
                    $update->addHandle('QS_'.$name); // QS_ prefix should prevent collisions
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check validity of arbitrary external string as XML safe
     *
     * @link http://stackoverflow.com/a/2519943/833795
     * @param string $name
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isValidXmlName($name)
    {
        try {
            new DOMElement($name);
            return true;
        } catch(DOMException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The effect can be checked by adding the following to the end of *./index.php*:

```
Zend_Debug::dump(Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());
```

This solution should be tested, especially with layout caching enabled. It might even be prudent to whitelist certain params.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this answer for whoever want's to achieve this.

To load a template from a different theme, you just have to keep the local.xml the same (the usual configuration), and then within the controller, add this code specifiying the package and theme to use to find the template file in:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')
->setPackageName('package')
->setTheme('theme');
```

This code was taken from how Magento applies a different theme for category pages when using "Custom Design". its tested and working on one of my live sites.