# PHP Encoding Error when producing XML from database

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I'm trying to get a simple PHP service to produce XML for an iPhone application, sourcing from an SQL database. The database has a variety of text sources and characters, some of which seem to be throwing off the script and producing the following encoding error:

error on line 1 at column 6232: Encoding error

The php is as follows:

```
<?php
    //database configuration
    $config['mysql_host'] = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX";
    $config['mysql_user'] = "XXXX";
    $config['mysql_pass'] = "XXXX";
    $config['db_name']    = "XXXX";
    $config['table_name'] = "articles";

    //connect to host
    mysql_connect($config['mysql_host'],$config['mysql_user'],$config['mysql_pass']);
    //select database
    @mysql_select_db($config['db_name']) or die( "Unable to select database");

$xml          = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
$root_element = $config['table_name']."s"; 
$xml         .= "<$root_element>";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$config['table_name'];

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    while($result_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $xml .= "<".$config['table_name'].">";

        //loop
        foreach($result_array as $key => $value)
        {

            $xml .= "<$key>";


            $xml .= "<![CDATA[$value]]>";

            //and close the element
            $xml .= "</$key>";
        }

        $xml.="</".$config['table_name'].">";
    }
}


$xml .= "</$root_element>";

//send xml
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");


echo $xml;
?>
```

Some articles cause the entire page to fail, some don't. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want help you need to ask a concrete question. That starts with finding out what exactly is causing the encoding error. Unless you're not able to, we're not able to help you either. (you see that with the different answers that are all likely guesses which as you can imagine is not helpful for you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is really broad, the best answer I can give is that you should use some existing library to encode the XML instead of writing your own one (as you obviously fail with the job hence the XML encoding error reported by the XML consument).

Using an existing library would also allow you to point out problems earlier. E.g. for the following code ensure all you get back from your database are UTF-8 encoded strings.

Also using a more modern database client class will also help you to greatly just write down the code. Here is an example with [`PDO`](http://php.net/PDO)  and [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DomDocument):

```
### configuration values

$config = array(
    'Database'     => array(
        'dsn'  => 'mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost;charset=utf8',
        'user' => 'testuser',
        'pass' => 'test',
    ),
    'table_name'   => 'config',
    'table_fields' => '*',
);

### implement database access

class Database extends PDO
{
    public function __construct(array $config = null)
    {
        $config = $config ? : $GLOBALS['config'][__CLASS__];
        parent::__construct($config['dsn'], $config['user'], $config['pass']);
        $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
        $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}

### setup the datasource ($rows)

$db   = new Database();
$rows = $db->query("SELECT $config[table_fields] FROM $config[table_name]");

### setup the XML encoder ($doc)

$doc               = new DOMDocument();
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->loadXML("<$config[table_name]s/>");
$doc->encoding = 'utf-8';

### fetch data from the datasource and encode the XML

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $child = $doc->createElement($config['table_name']);
    $child = $doc->documentElement->appendChild($child);
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        $child->appendChild($doc->createElement($key, $value));
    }
}

### output XML

header("Content-Type:text/xml");
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

See that `DomDocument` is taking care here of properly encoding the UTF-8 strings that are returned from the database. There is (normally) no need for `<![CDATA[...]]>` here any longer. As you can imagine you likely put something in there that broke your XML encoding.

Also for the database interaction, most of your code is not necessary either, you can just iterate over the rows, if there ain't no rows, there would be no iteration. This is normally best expressed with an `Iterator` the `foreach` language construct can operate on which is provided by modern database interfaces. Technically you can replace `$rows` here with many other things, like an iterator that goes over multiple tables one after the other.

Additionally using the exception error mode does spare you to place checks and `die`s all over your codebase.

An exemplary output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configs>
  <config>
    <id>1</id>
    <option>value for option with ID1</option>
  </config>
  <config>
    <id>2</id>
    <option>value for option with ID2</option>
  </config>
  ...
</configs>
```

If you then still need to create CDATA elements, it works similarly (I show only a part of the script here, which only contains a slight modification adding CDATA sections instead of a child value):

```
### fetch data from the datasource and encode the XML

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $child = $doc->createElement($config['table_name']);
    $child = $doc->documentElement->appendChild($child);
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        $child->appendChild($doc->createElement($key))
              ->appendChild($doc->createCDATASection($value))
        ;
    }
}
```

Here as well, `DOMDocument` takes care of properly encoding the CDATA section. Something likely you didn't do.

Potential problems you still might run into are with table or row names that are [invalid XML names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519845/how-to-check-if-string-is-a-valid-xml-element-name). But then `DOMDocument` will actually tell you so you know while generating the XML, not only afterwards with an encoding error.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_connect($config['mysql_host'],$config['mysql_user'],$config['mysql_pass']);
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
mysql_select_db($config['db_name']);
```

Answer (score -1):

As you have described the XML format as utf8 thus all the character in the XML File must be utf8 characters.

You are getting the error as there are non UTF8 Characters. You have to change the Character to UFT8 format and there are two ways for checking UTF8 characters

## Way 1

```
if (mb_check_encoding(file_get_contents($file), 'UTF-8')) {
    // yup, all UTF-8
}
```

This way it make sure that all the characters are UTF8 compatible and if any row is not according to utf8 then left out.

## Way 2

```
mysql_connect($config['mysql_host'],$config['mysql_user'],$config['mysql_pass']);
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
mysql_select_db($config['db_name']);
```

## Way 3

```
<xml>
 <![CDATA[

   ///Enter the Test here


 ]]>
</xml>
```