# Error deserializing a php soap webservice with a .NET WCF Client

Tags: php, .net, xml, soap, webservice-client

I am having an issue in deserializing the soap XML from a php web service

The XML that is coming back from the web service has a tag `<item xsi:type="xsd:">`

Basically its saying `type=""` which throws an error:

> “The specified type was not recognized: name=':'”

is the attribute `xsi:type="xsd:"` valid?

I've asked out client to remove it but they are saying they cannot.

Answer (score 0):

> is the attribute `xsi:type="xsd:"` valid?

No it is not. The (optional) attribute `xsi:type` is used in *validation* of the document to specify a type of that element. That attribute is setting the type of that element *explicitly*.

However `xsd:` is an *invalid* type. Because it does not specify any type. It's an unfinished *QName* of the type, it only conains the `xsd:` prefix with no *local-name*  of the type followed. This is completely invalid and hence the type can not be defined.

Because the type can not be defined (you can not define a type with a zero-length *local-name*), the validation *must* fail.

Clarify of which type that element has to be in the first place and then consider to create your own SOAP client that is able to deal with these (incomplete, invalid) specs in the first place.

Tell your client what the problem is, what the consequences are and that you can't repay their technical debt at this point in time without re-negotiating the development because they so far told you the wrong preconditions for your work: They don't give a *valid* SOAP response with their webservice. It's probably that they didn't notice so far, so you have the shit job to tell them that they are at fault. Take care and good luck.

- http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#xsi_type
- http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#src-qname

See as well:

- [How to check if string is a valid XML element name?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15188815/367456)