# Is <:nodename> a valid xml node name?

Tags: xml, validation, specifications, nodename

I read milions of questions about xml node naming rules. But none of them answer the simple question: **Can the node name start with colon?**

Example:

```
<:nodename>Inner text</:nodename>
```

*This can be associated with empty namespace (global namespace). But not sure if this is valid, and what is the possible usage of such a name.*

PS. No real application of code, or ideas where to use it, just curiosity and self-learning purposes.

PS 2. Some research links:

- this one: http://www.xmlvalidation.com says it is wrong (but it cannot be trusted I think)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2519943/1125465 (great answer btw) says it is ok
- http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/ - *The Namespaces in XML Recommendation [XML Names] assigns a meaning to names containing colon characters. Therefore, authors should not use the colon in XML names except for namespace purposes, but XML processors must accept the colon as a name character.* Still no answer...

Comment: Of course I'm asking about XML1.1 specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's well-formed according to the XML 1.0 and XML 1.1 specifications, but not according to the namespaces specification. Most people (and software) require XML to be namespace-well-formed, so it would be definitely best to avoid it.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Short, but concrete. +1, accepted!