# XMLException. List of the all invalid characters

Tags: c#, xml, exception

I try execute such a code sample.

```
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
documentTagName = "testName)"
XmlNode headerElement = xmlDocument.CreateElement(documentTagName);
```

Of cource I get **XmlException**:

*The ')' character, hexadecimal value 0x... (doesn't matter), cannot be included in a name*

Because I have `)` symbol in `documentTagName`. And of cource I'll get the same exception if `documentTagName` would be like this:

```
documentTagName = "testName("
```

or like this:

```
documentTagName = "testName:"
```

Because all of these characters (`'('` , `')'` , `':'`) are invalid for the xml tag name. But I check many links (and even  [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Char)) and cannot find the **list of all invalid characters** for xml tag name. Can anybody help me?

Comment: WC3 XML Spec, element name section: http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-Name. It's more complex than a simple sequence (unicode also comes in). There are some RegEx's which will tell you  if it's a 'legal'. (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519845/how-to-check-if-string-is-a-valid-xml-element-name)

Comment: @Marvin Smit, In your link I see only this `PubidChar    ::=    #x20 | #xD | #xA | [a-zA-Z0-9] | [-'()+,./:=?;!*#@$_%]`

Comment: 1st link: w3.org link => Official XML specifications. Starts at "Names and Tokens". 2nd link: Shows essentially same question but for PHP. Regex's shown there are still useful.

Comment: @Marvin Smit, I need the **list of illegal characters**, but you suppose me rules how to form name of xml node corretly or check the name correctness with Regex. Thx, but it is not quite what I want.

Comment: There isn't a "list of illegal characters". It's a complex sequence where some character are allowed from position 2, but not as first char. etc...