# Convert CSV to XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml, csv, data-conversion

I have multiple CSV files in a folder with different data. I want to read in 1 CSV file at a time, convert the data to XML and then output the file as .xml before reading in the next CSV file.

Currently, the CSV files that I have all have a header row in it. The code I ave right now runs fine for all the CSV files that have a header row in it.

However, when it reads in a file that does not have a header row in it, it throws an error. I want it to be able to detect if there is no headings in the header row and then make it input strings which have been preset in variables in the code. Is this possible?

**Current Code**

```
function converttoxml( $input_filename ) {

echo $input_filename;

//set the delimiter
$delimiter = "," ;

//set count to 0
$row_count++ ;

//strip the input filename of the extension
$stripped = pathinfo($input_filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

//set output filename
$outputFilename  = UPLOAD_DIR."/".$stripped.".xml";

//open inputfilename
$inputFile  = fopen( $input_filename, 'rt' );

//get input file pointers for csv parsing
$headers = fgetcsv( $inputFile );

//create new DOM document
$doc  = new DomDocument();

//set the output to clean
$doc->formatOutput = true;

//create element
$root = $doc->createElement( 'Shipping_Details' );

$root = $doc->appendChild( $root );

//while there are rows in the csv file
while ( ( $row = fgetcsv( $inputFile ) ) !== FALSE ) {

    //create container row
    $container = $doc->createElement('Job_Header_Details');

        //for loop
        foreach ( $headers as $i => $header ) {

            //explode with the delimiter the header
            $arr = explode( $delimiter, $header );

            //print_r($arr);

                //for loop
                foreach ( $arr as $key => $ar ) {

                    //only accept regualar expressions matching this
                    $child = $doc->createElement(preg_replace( "/[^A-Za-z0-9]/","",$ar ) );

                    //add the previous child to $child
                    $child = $container->appendChild( $child );

                    //explode row with delimiter
                    $whole = explode( $delimiter, $row[$i] );

                    //left and right trim anything with speechmarks
                    $value = $doc->createTextNode( ltrim( rtrim( $whole[$key], '"') ,'"') );

                    //append previous value to $value
                    $value = $child->appendChild( $value );

                }//for
        }//for

   //append to root - container
   $root->appendChild($container);

}//while



echo "Saving the XML file\n" ;

$result = $doc->saveXML();

echo "Writing to the XML file\n" ;

$handle = fopen( $outputFilename, "w" );

fwrite( $handle, $result );

fclose( $handle );

return $outputFilename;
```

**Examples of CSV files that will/willnot process**

[CSV File example that will work with above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfFiN.png)

[CSV File example that will **NOT** work with the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fARsg.png)

With the example that will not work, I believe it is because the header row is missing. In this case, I want to somehow define what each column heading should be and input it in.

for example

```
$column_1 = "<heading1>";
$column_2 = "<heading2>";
$column_3 = "<heading3>";
$column_4 = "<heading4>";
$column_5 = "<heading5>";
$column_6 = "<heading6>";
```

etc..

So when the script runs and it detects headings in the CSV file, it will use them. But when it detects that they are not there, the it will use the above $column examples to input the  in.

**The error I get when a CSV file does not have a header description**

[image: Missing header error]

Any ideas?

Comment: You will have to check when you've read the headers that each name is a valid xml element name, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519845/how-to-check-if-string-is-a-valid-xml-element-name gives a regex to check them, so parse each one by this and replace ones that are invalid.

Comment: Good question. Can you edit your post and add the csv files not as screenshots but as text? How? Simply open csv in any text editor (not Excel or other spreadsheet app) and then copy+paste a few top rows into body of your post, formatting it with SO's `{}` button on toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Just to try this out, added ...

```
    //get input file pointers for csv parsing
    $headers = fgetcsv( $inputFile );

    $row = 1;
    foreach ( $headers as &$header )   {
        if (preg_match('/\A(?!XML)[a-z][\w0-9-]*/i', $header) === 0 ) {
           $header = 'heading'.$row;
        }
        $row++;
    }
    unset($header);
```

Which when passed in a header of `a,1223` produces headers of `a,heading2`.  Whereas `a,b` gives `a,b`.

Update: Although if any element fails, you'll want to process this row as data by the look of it.